# Get disabled text color from theme?

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library

With a built in `TextAppearance` such as **@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline** my TextView has a nice faded out textcolor when disabled. This is neat and beautiful. I want to mimic this behavior when using a custom color selector. Its important that the colors rely on the themes color as I have dark/light themes in the app that should switch naturally with Androids built in day/night flags.

Heres my selector, and this is used in a `TextView` attribute as `android:textColor="selector_here"`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="____________" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="?colorAccent" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:color="?android:textColorSecondary"/>
</selector>
```

Ive tried using **?android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly** which to me sounds like the primary text colors, with only the disabled state. No success.

Edit: On the contrary, using **?android:textColorSecondaryNoDisable** gives me the disabled state. I would think that this does not contain a disabled state properly, judging from the name of it. Still, I am looking for the textColorPrimary disabled state, though!

*I have indeed set the enabled="false" flag on the view :)*

---

**How can I point to the disabled primary text color through the selector, while keeping it themed according to androids day/night flags (i.e. no hard-coding of the color)?**